How to resolve local env vars in Serverless Framework V4?
I've recently started a project using Serverless V4, but I'm not able to get the variables from my .env, I'm using serverless-offline as plugin, Node.js v21.7.1.
This is my serverless.yml
# "org" ensures this Service is used with the correct Serverless Framework Access Key.
org: kennethlg
# "app" enables Serverless Framework Dashboard features and sharing them with other Services.
app: hoost
# "service" is the name of this project. This will also be added to your AWS resource names.
service: my-project

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x
functions:
  getListings:
    handler: src/controllers/getListings/index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /listings
          method: get
  login:
    handler: src/controllers/login/index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /login
          method: get
plugins:
  - serverless-offline

const responseHandler = require("../../libs/response");
const { login } = require("../../services/hostaway");

module.exports.handler = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await login();
    return responseHandler.success(data, 'Login successful');
  } catch (error) {
    return responseHandler.error('Couldn\'t login sucessfully');
  }
} 

const { instance } = require('../libs/axios');
const config = require('../config');

const login = async () => {
  try {
    console.log(config)
    const data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    data.append('client_id', config.hostawayId);
    data.append('client_secret', config.hostawayApiKey);
    data.append('scope', 'general');

    const response = await instance.post('/accessTokens', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      }
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(" ~ login ~ error:", error);
    throw new Error('Error authenticating to Hostaway');
  }
}


I get a 500 error because my env vars are not set correctly:
const config = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  hostawayApiKey: process.env.HOSTAWAY_API_KEY,
  hostawayId: parseInt(process.env.HOSTAWAY_ID)
}

module.exports = config;

Server ready: http://localhost:3000 


GET /login (λ: login)
{ port: 3000, hostawayApiKey: undefined, hostawayId: NaN }

I read the documentation and it says that serverless v4 is already configured to use use local environments, but as I mentioned before, it isn't working. This is the documentation: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs-providers-aws-guide-variables

You have to configure env in environment object under a function configuration

In previous versions of Serverless Framework (<= V.3), the useDotEnv configuration in serverless.yml would have to be set in order to load .env and [stage].env files, and make their environment variables accessible within serverless.yml.
In V.4, these files are read automatically, without the useDotEnv property, this mean you can access the .env variables inside the serverless.yml not in lambda environment automatically.
Solution
You have to configure lambda environment variables manually in serverless.yml

If you want to variable configuration to a specific function by adding an environment object property in the function configuration. This object should contain a key-value pairs of string to string like below.
 functions:
   getListings:
     handler: src/controllers/getListings/index.handler
     environment:
       HOSTAWAY_API_KEY: ${env:HOSTAWAY_API_KEY}
       HOSTAWAY_ID: ${env:HOSTAWAY_ID}
     events:
       - httpApi:
           path: /listings
           method: get


Or if you want to apply environment variable configuration to all functions in your service, you can add the configuration to the higher level provider object
 provider:
   name: aws
   runtime: nodejs20.x
   environment:
         HOSTAWAY_API_KEY: ${env:HOSTAWAY_API_KEY}
         HOSTAWAY_ID: ${env:HOSTAWAY_ID}




The .env file won't be read automatically - you need to do it yourself, e.g., by using the dotenv package:
require('dotenv').config()


In this documentation (Upgrading from v3 to v4) says: "Environment Variables Loaded By Default
In previous versions of Serverless Framework (<= V.3), the useDotEnv configuration in serverless.yml would have to be set in order to load .env and [stage].env files, and make their environment variables accessible within serverless.yml.
In V.4, these files are read automatically, without the useDotEnv property."
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v4
Do you think, I still need to install dotenv?
